# Calling method in Twig, how to avoid the return showing as output

Tags: twig

I am calling a method in a pre-existing object from inside a Twig template, after properly authorizing it in policy:

```
{{ thisEmail.AddCC('me@example.com') }}
```

My problem is that the object method, which I use to produce a side-effect, not to return any text, returns true, and that leaves a visible "1" in my template output.

How to remove this output? I have this one working:

```
{{ thisEmail.AddCC('me@example.com')|trim('1') }}
```

But I feel it's not entirely elegant, and it can only remove that specific result. I would prefer to write something like `|nul` or `|drop` and have the filter drop everything, regardless of how much or what kind of stuff it receives as input.

I know how to do it by writing my own Twig extension filters, but my question here is: **is there a nice way of achieving this with the core Twig language, un-extended?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `twig` statement not to output anything you can use the `do` tag, e.g.

```
{% do thisEmail.AddCC('me@example.com') %}
```

[source](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/do.html)

Comment: I was getting an error `Unexpected token "name" of value "thisEmail" ("end of print statement" expected).`, but it turned out I neglected to change my `{{` to  `{%`. With that change, it works, and I like it, it's elegant. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you understood my edit. That `| trim(1)` was not part of my original twig source. I added it as an imperfect solution. With the better solution provided in your answer, it doesn't make sense to keep that there; it makes it confusing to understand why would both solutions be needed. If you re-read my question carefully you'll understand. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the edit suggested just added the trim, didn't see the `trim(1)` was there already - Anyway the trim shoudln't add/remove anything as there is no output anyway